# Redirecting a child process' stdout and stderr to two named pipes (then reading back from them)

Tags: unix, redirect, named-pipes, child-process

I'm working on an application that popen()s another process, whose output - both stderr and stderr - needs to be redirected to two named pipes, also created by the application. Then I need to read data back from the pipes.

```
mkfifo("output.fifo", 0666); // error checks etc.
mkfifo("error.fifo", 0666); // error checks etc.
popen("cstuff 'param' < input.txt 1> output.fifo 2> error.fifo", "r");
```

does not work: the application hangs when I try to read from **error.fifo**. `sleep()`ing / `wait()`ing between `mkfifo()` and `popen()` doesn't work either.

```
// output.txt is the result from a file dialog
popen("cstuff 'param' < input.txt 1> output.txt 2> error.fifo", "r");
```

does work.

```
popen("cstuff 'param' < input.txt 1> output.fifo", "r");
```

also works.

```
$ cstuff 'param' < input.txt 1> output.txt 2> output.txt
```

from the the shell also works (but not from my application).

I couldn't find a straightforward (or any) way to get reading from both pipes working. How can that be achieved?

Comment: 9  Why is this tagged with 'bash'?

Comment: nhed, because `popen(3)` uses `sh -c` to execute programs

Comment: @sarnold: `man 3 popen` (at least on my system) says `/bin/sh -c` is used which is very often not Bash.

Comment: @nhed, fair point, it isn't that closely related - removed tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try just `system(3)` instead of `popen(3)`; you're not using the `FILE*` returned from `popen(3)`, because you're not using `popen(3)` as it was meant to be used. But this ought to work fine from `system(3)`.

Comment: while the use of popen() really not entirely adequate in the example, switching to system() does not solve the problem. (what is the (3) notation for btw?)

Comment: Hrm, then perhaps pelya's answer is on the right track. The `(3)` means the manual page is in the third section; `printf(1)` and `printf(3)` are two different manual pages, and the section helps identify which one is meant. It's less necessary with `popen(3)`, but old habits die hard. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should call poll() or select() on file descriptors of both output.fifo and error.fifo, and call read() only when there is a data ready.

I suggest you to use [pstreams](http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/) instead of ugly named pipes.

Comment: +1: using poll() helped to stop the hanging, however, given a 1s wait, poll() comes back with no event at all. (tried all priority / normal, read / write variants; when I $ myapp 1> out.txt 2> err.txt, there is no noticeable wait, so I'm assuming that 1s should be more than enough.)

any ideas on where my stderr is going? (I'm referring to the file I'm sending it to as a const char *, so no chance of typo there.)